# Laravel echo can't listen channel when deploying app on server

Tags: javascript, laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

I have a laravel 9 App and vueJs 3. I use laravel pusher to send messages on real time and listen to channels in front-end with laravel echo like this :

```
Echo.private(`messages.${this.room.id}`).listen(".new-message", (e) => {
        console.log("done")
        this.chats.push({
          message: e.message.message,
          image_path : e.message.image_path,
          from_id: e.from.id,
          to_id: e.to.id,
          from: e.from,
        })
```

the configuration in `bootstrap` file:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ?? `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});
```

.env file :

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher    
PUSHER_APP_ID=1******
PUSHER_APP_KEY=6******
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=8*********
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=eu

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

all works fine at `localhost` and messages was recieving at real time, but when I deploy the app on server , it's not working , I can't listen to the channel. I don't know if I must append another configuration

Any suggestions ? 
thank's

Comment: Could you add the error you are getting in your question? Thanks in advance

Comment: @RobBiermann I didn't got any error , it can't enter to this function `Echo.private(`messages.${this.room.id}`).listen`  because the log I set it in this function it is not shown in dev tools

Comment: I have exactly the opposed 'issue'(i dont want to solve it because its a non-issue in my case). I configured my websockets to work with the live environment, but it does not work with localhost. For me I see the error in devtools.  Could you check the devtools->network->ws->messages?(if chrome) Maybe also confirm what url and port the websocket is trying to connect to?

Comment: @RobBiermann I'm not familiar enough with dev tools, there are just websokets with random name in `network->ws` , there is no messages

Comment: Allright, can you confirm where the websocket is connecting to? should be something like `wss://yoursite.com:6001/something`

Comment: Btw, small comment, your statement `(import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https'` can be reduced to `import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? true`

Comment: @RobBiermann it connet to `wss://ws-eu.pusher.com/app/6ab1b980b352c9ab3806?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.4.0&flash=false`  with status `101`

Comment: That actually looks fine. Can you confirm your `broadcasting/auth` request returns 200? This is necessary to get into a private channel. Maybe you should check if you can get it to work with a public channel first as this requires less parameters. If you get that to work, then step into the private channel issue.

Comment: @RobBiermann there are two socket's message , the first : `{"event":"pusher:connection_established","data":"{\"socket_id\":\"137232.732942\",\"activity_timeout\":120}"}`  and  the second  :  `{"event":"pusher:error","data":{"code":4009,"message":"Connection not authorized within timeout"}}
`

Comment: @RobBiermann Yes `broadcasting/auth` return 200

Comment: Thats good, it's hard to fix a problem without a message. This helps pinpointing the issue alot! Seems like your authorization is failing which explains why you cant join a private channel. I would use this error message to find out why you are not authenticating, maybe check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66367538/pusher-typepushererror-datacode4009-messageconnection-not

Comment: @RobBiermann I have already enable Authorised Connections in your Pusher App settings from the begining but nothing change :(

Comment: Could you try to turn it off and see if it works then? It's not a permanent solution but at least we could verify it is causing the issue or not

Comment: @RobBiermann no it's not the issue I turned it off but the same warning ..  I have this in chanel : `Broadcast::channel('messages.{RoomId}', function $user, $RoomId) { if(Auth::check()) return ['id' => $RoomId];}); ` maybe the issue comes from here

Comment: Yeah I believe, but am not certain, that you just need to return a boolean here. True is ok, false is deny(https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting#defining-authorization-callbacks)

Comment: @RobBiermann Yes after this I see the docs and I tried to return all the time true but the issue not fixed :( I'm disappointed

Comment: Yeah I can imagine. I'm out of ideas as well. Maybe do a very rigorous comparison between your localhost and your server. Since you say it's working on localhost, you have everything set correctly there, there must be something on your server that is not right. Maybe you set something in pusher that it only accepts connection from your local ip and not the servers. I wish I could help further, but since I use laravel-websocket and not pusher.com itself, there are too many differences

Comment: @RobBiermann I will see, anyway thank you for your tips and suggestions :)

Comment: @RobBiermann Thank you for your help :) finaly I resolved this issue (check answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Slution**

I resolved this issue by adding customize the authorization endpoint check [Customizing The Authorization Endpoint](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting#customizing-the-authorization-endpoint)
docs from laravel

web.php :

```
Route::post('/pusher/user-auth', [PusherController::class, 'pusherAuth']);
```

PusherController :

```
/**
 * Authenticates logged-in user in the Pusher JS app
 * For private channels
 */
public function pusherAuth(Request $request)
{

    $user = auth()->user();
    $socket_id = $request['socket_id'];
    $channel_name =$request['channel_name'];
    $key = config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.key'); 
    $secret = config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.secret'); 
    $app_id = config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.app_id'); 
    if ($user) {
 
        $pusher = new Pusher($key, $secret, $app_id);
        $auth = $pusher->socketAuth($channel_name, $socket_id);
        return response($auth, 200);

    } else {
        header('', true, 403);
        echo "Forbidden";
        return;
    }
}
```

and the bootstrap file :

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ?? `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
    wsPort: 443, //import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: 443, //import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS:  (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
    disableStats: true,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    authEndpoint: "/pusher/user-auth", // this is the new endpoint for auth
    encrypted: true,
});
```

and finaly don't froget to change the **`BROADCAST_DRIVER`**  in `.env` file to `pusher` not `log`